# How to locate where error arises in a WinRT async method call?

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, windows-runtime, ida

I'm debugging a WinRT async method call which fails. How can I locate where the problem arises? I think this could be done by tracking where the error is firstly reported. Any clues? I'm using IDA Pro & VS 2013.

After deeply debugging I think I found where the error is fristly read - by the ntdll "NtGetCompleteWnfStateSubscription" undocomented function (you could check the linked question for more details about it). But I can't seek what function sets it. Also I can't debug the "NtGetCompleteWnfStateSubscription" function itself as it's a kernel one.

This is a more generic question. It's origin from this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003511/how-to-locate-where-an-error-arises-in-a-packagemanager-addpackageasync-method).

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `RoOriginateError`. Inproc components usually call this function at the point the error is generated.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I set a breakpoint on this function but it seems that is called a way after "NtGetCompleteWnfStateSubscription" which was the function it seems really query the error.

Comment: So it seems it is actually called to report the recieved error but not to state for it from the WinRT method.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is I wrap an async call in a task using `create_task()` and in `.then()` lambda - call `task.get()` in a `try-catch` block. That gives me the exception.